# While and continue issue

Tags: python, while-loop, continue

could you please help me to understand what i'm doing wrong.
I have two lists below and i need if x will be !=' ' in board => continue to input x until it will be ' '. Thank you in advance.

```
board = [' ', ' ', 'X', ' ', ' ', ' ']
testlist_1 = ['x','y', 'z']

x = int(input('>'))

while True:
    if board[x] == ' ':
        for i in range (len (testlist_1)):
            board[x] = testlist_1[i]
            x += 1
            if board[x] !=' ':
             break
    else:
       x = int (input ('>'))
       continue


   #I need:
   #input:x = 2
   #board = [' ', ' ', 'X', ' ', ' ', ' ']
   #ask x 
   #input:x =0
   #board = ['x', 'y', 'X', ' ', ' ', ' ']
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be `if board[x] != ' '`?

Comment: @JakubBláha isn't an `else` there?

Comment: He has there *"I have two lists below and i need if x will be !=' '..."* not *"if x == ' '"*.

Comment: if board[x] == ' ' go to for loop, else ask for another x until board[x] == ' '

Comment: what is the purpose of `testlist_1` ?

Comment: testlist _1 it is just example (it included into another dictionary in my future code)

Comment: As a developer this question can be read. Not sure why it was closed but it came up as a "test" for me to review and according to the system the question cannot be understood, lol. I voted leave it open and got "stop and listen".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give this a try, I added a few print statements so you can see what the board looks like each loop:

```
board = [' ', ' ', 'X', ' ', ' ', ' ']
testlist_1 = ['x','y', 'z']

while True:
    x = int(input('>'))
    if board[x] == ' ':
        for test_item in testlist_1:
            board[x] = test_item
            x += 1
            if board[x] !=' ':
                break
        break
    print(board)
print(board)
```

IO:

```
>2
[' ', ' ', 'X', ' ', ' ', ' ']
>0
['x', 'y', 'X', ' ', ' ', ' ']
```

Comment: Thanks, it works if only add try and else block otherwise it cause IndexError. My goal is to clarify why my initial code it doesn't work when i use range

Comment: please update your question to reflect this, and provide some example inputs and outputs of the functionality you want.

Comment: Dear ktzr thank you for your help but could you please explain why we need use break two times. Thank you in advance

Comment: One to break out the `for` and one to break out the `while` loop